# Generate function parameters from a combination of initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to automatize calling a function multiple times using a combination of parameters. Something like:

```cpp
int sum3(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
}

std::vector<int> v = foo<sum3>({1, 2}, 0, {2, 3});

// Equivalent to:
// v.emplace_back(sum3(1, 0, 2));
// v.emplace_back(sum3(1, 0, 3));
// v.emplace_back(sum3(2, 0, 2));
// v.emplace_back(sum3(2, 0, 3));
```

Is something like this possible in C++20 using template metaprogramming?

**Update**
I would be interested in nesting these expressions. For example:

```cpp
int bar(int a) {
    return a + 1;
}

std::vector<int> v = foo<sum3>({1, 2}, foo<bar>({0, 1}), {2, 3});

// Equivalent to:
// std::vector<int> v = foo<sum3>({1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 3});
```

Comment: Would it be OK to force the user to make *all* of the parameters braced-init-lists? That is, your example would have to be `foo<sum3>({1, 2}, {0}, {2, 3});`

Comment: Yes, that would be ok

Answer (score 1):

This will much simpler with the help of [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)

```
template<auto f, class... Ts>
auto foo(std::initializer_list<Ts>... il) {
  return ranges::views::cartesian_product(il...)
       | ranges::views::transform([](auto t) { 
           return std::apply([](auto... args) { return f(args...); }, t);
         })
       | ranges::to<std::vector>;
}

std::vector v = foo<sum3>({1, 2}, {0}, {2, 3});
```

where [`views::cartesian_product`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2374r3.html) has tier 1 priority in the [C++23 ranges plan](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2214r2.html), and [`ranges::to`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1206r7.pdf) has been adopted by C++23.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rYhMWrz4E)

Comment: I don't mind using ranges (although I'd prefer a pure templates solution). But I need to nest these expressions (see updated answer).

Comment: That's a completely *different* question. You should open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accept brace-enclosed initilizer lists, values and other collections, like vectors, you'll need a helper class. Something like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct span_or_init_list
{
    span_or_init_list(std::initializer_list<T> list)
        : span(list)
    {}

    span_or_init_list(std::span<const T> span)
        : span(span)
    {}

    span_or_init_list(T const &val)
        : span(&val, 1)
    {}

    template<typename Range>
    span_or_init_list(Range const &v)
        : span(v)
    {}

    std::span<const T> span;
};
```

Unfortunately the compiler cannot deduce `span_or_init_list<T>` from something like `{0, 1}`, so you need to do something metaprogramming to write `foo`.

Since partial function template specialization is limited, a `constexpr` variable could be used instead:

```
template<auto func, typename FuncT = decltype(func)>
inline constexpr int foo;

template<auto func, typename Ret, typename ...Args>
std::vector<Ret> foo_impl(span_or_init_list<std::decay_t<Args>> ...list)
{
    // do work here
}

template<auto func, typename Ret, typename ...Args>
inline constexpr auto foo<func, Ret(*)(Args...)> = foo_impl<func, Ret, Args...>;
```

For the implementation of `foo_impl` you could for example use @康桓瑋's solution from their answer.

So in the end these calls work:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = foo<sum3>({1, 2}, 0, {2, 3});
std::vector<int> v2 = foo<sum3>({1, 2}, foo<abs>({0, 1}), {2, 3});
```

[See full example on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/1xxnx8b6n)